# Can't send email using gmail-smtp with javamail?

Tags: java, email, gmail

I'm using Javamail to sned the email from my gmail to others but the system couldn't send it. It keeps on saying it couldn't load main class.

The code I got was a demo code so I think it's not the problem. Anyhow, I'm posting it here.

```
package Email;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "abc@gmail.com";
        final String password = "abc";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("def@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I've set my CLASSPATH with all the jar in `D:\...` and also the place where I store my .java file. There's no space in the link.
When I compiled, the program did it just fine. The problem started when I tried to run the code.

`

```
PS D:\Documents\java> javac SendMailTLS.java
PS D:\Documents\java> java SendMailTLS
Error: Could not find or load main class SendMailTLS
PS D:\Documents\java>
PS D:\Documents\java> java Email.SendMailTLS
Error: Could not find or load main class Email.SendMailTLS
PS D:\Documents\java>
PS D:\Documents\java> java .Email.SendMailTLS
Error: Could not find or load main class .Email.SendMailTLS
PS D:\Documents\java>
PS D:\Documents\java> java -cp D:\Documents\java\ Email.SendMailTLS
Error: Could not find or load main class Email.SendMailTLS
PS D:\Documents\java>
PS D:\Documents\java> java -cp D:\Documents\java\ SendMailTLS
Error: Could not find or load main class SendMailTLS
PS D:\Documents\java>
`
```

Any idea why it's like this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Zestos.

Comment: I've looked over that post and tried it their way but to no avail. I'm really in need of this program and haven't been able to figure out what's wrong with it. It's been 3 days and I can't understand why. Tried the CLASSPATH, tried the `.\` with the package name too. None are working? Any help?

Comment: You have to call `javac Email.SendMailTLS.java` and then call 
java -cp ./ java `Email.SendMailTLS` and your file `SendMailTLS.java` must located in directory `java\Email`

Comment: Thanks @Jens. It really solved my problem of "could not load main class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your class to be in the package "Email". The class loader will search for this class in a subdirectory "Email", not in the current directory. Create a directory "Email" in a directory of your classpath, or under the current directory, and move your class there. Then call the class as `Email.SendMailTLS`

Alternatively just remove the `package` statement from your class.

BTW, naming convention is to keep the package name in lowercase.

Comment: Great! This solved my problem of the "could not load mail class". Thanks a lot. But now I'm getting this problem.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a
 STARTTLS command first. df1sm1421038pbb.2 - gsmtp

        at email.SendMailTLS.main(SendMailTLS.java:48)`
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the property `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` to false like this :

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
```